# Create a time varying and time invariant contextual variables in r

Tags: r, dplyr, multilevel-analysis

I am attempting to do a longitudinal multilevel model using ESS survey data from 2002-2018. I want to look at the effects of macroeconomic performance on political trust. In order to do this I am using a 'within-between' approach which models a cross sectional and longitudinal component simultaneously.

Right now I have a dataset in which I have added the actual inflation,GDP growth and unemployment rates for each country-year. In order to create a time invariant component, I have to create a variable which is the mean (GDP growth, inflation, unemployment), for each country over the entire time series (e.g mean GDP growth for Austria 2002-2018). However, when I run it using the code below, it creates a variable with the mean of the overall dataset for the contextual variables as opposed to the mean by country.

```
data<-data%>%
  group_by(country)%>%
  mutate( inflation_mean = mean(inflation, na.rm = TRUE),
          inflation_diff = inflation - inflation_mean,
          growth_mean = mean(GDPgrowth, na.rm = TRUE),
          growth_diff = GDPgrowth - growth_mean,
          unemployment_mean = mean(unemployment,na.rm = TRUE),
          unemployment_diff = unemployment - unemployment_mean)
```

This is an example of what my data frame looks like

```
#     country  year country_year  trust  inflation GDPGrowth Unemployment
# 1   Austria  2002  AT2002       4      2.2       4.2          4
# 2   Austria  2002  AT2002       9      2.2       4.2          4
# 55  Belgium  2002  BE2002       7      1.7       2.5          6
# 56  Belgium  2002  BE2002       3      1.7       2.5          6
# 91  Austria  2005  AT2005       2      3.4       2.9          3
# 91  Austria  2005  AT2005       6      3.4       2.9          3
# 141 Belgium  2005  BE2005       5      0.5       1.6          5
# 142 Belgium  2005  BE2005       9      0.5       1.6          5
```

```
structure(list(idno = structure(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7), format.stata = "%12.0g"), 
    cntry = structure(c("AT", "AT", "AT", "AT", "AT", "AT"), format.stata = "%2s"), 
    essround = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), format.stata = "%12.0g"), 
    pspwght = structure(c(0.9409328155361, 0.47046640776805, 
    1.39215496052674, 1.38216297191755, 1.43776626993043, 1.39215496052674
    ), format.stata = "%12.0g"), agea = structure(c(54, 50, 63, 
    44, 41, 63), format.stata = "%13.0g"), gndr = structure(c(1, 
    1, 2, 1, 2, 2), format.stata = "%12.0g"), eduyrs = structure(c(11, 
    14, 9, 18, 15, 11), format.stata = "%12.0g"), mnactic = structure(c(1, 
    1, 6, 1, 1, 6), format.stata = "%41.0g"), lrscale = structure(c(6, 
    6, 5, 5, 5, NA), format.stata = "%12.0g"), rlgdgr = structure(c(8, 
    5, 7, 7, 10, 3), format.stata = "%20.0g"), dscrgrp = structure(c(2, 
    1, 2, 2, 2, 1), format.stata = "%12.0g"), dscretn = structure(c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), format.stata = "%12.0g"), ctzcntr = structure(c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1), format.stata = "%12.0g"), blgetmg = structure(c(2, 
    2, NA, 2, 2, 2), format.stata = "%12.0g"), hincfel = structure(c(1, 
    3, 2, 1, 1, 3), format.stata = "%36.0g"), trstprl = structure(c(9, 
    0, 6, 8, 6, 0), format.stata = "%15.0g"), inwyr = structure(c(2003, 
    2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003), format.stata = "%13.0g"), 
    inwyys = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), format.stata = "%13.0g"), inwyye = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), format.stata = "%13.0g"), 
    education = structure(c(11, 14, 9, 18, 15, 11), format.stata = "%12.0g"), 
    female = structure(c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1), format.stata = "%12.0g"), 
    employement = structure(c(1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 6), format.stata = "%41.0g"), 
    age = structure(c(54, 50, 63, 44, 41, 63), format.stata = "%13.0g"), 
    year = c(2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003), year1 = c(2010, 
    2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010), year0 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
    ), cntry_year = c("AT 2003", "AT 2003", "AT 2003", "AT 2003", 
    "AT 2003", "AT 2003"), n = c(2257L, 2257L, 2257L, 2257L, 
    2257L, 2257L), year_lag = c(2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 
    2002), gini_disp = c(26.7, 26.7, 26.7, 26.7, 26.7, 26.7), 
    unemployment = c("4.849999905", "4.849999905", "4.849999905", 
    "4.849999905", "4.849999905", "4.849999905"), corruption = c(1.966434, 
    1.966434, 1.966434, 1.966434, 1.966434, 1.966434), wb_growth = structure(c(1.65155392186669, 
    1.65155392186669, 1.65155392186669, 1.65155392186669, 1.65155392186669, 
    1.65155392186669), label = "GDP growth (annual %)"), wb_inflation = structure(c(1.81035787764132, 
    1.81035787764132, 1.81035787764132, 1.81035787764132, 1.81035787764132, 
    1.81035787764132), label = "Inflation, consumer prices (annual %)"), 
    old_demo = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), gini_mean = c(28.9443587367257, 
    28.9443587367257, 28.9443587367257, 28.9443587367257, 28.9443587367257, 
    28.9443587367257), gini_diff = c(-2.24435873672569, -2.24435873672569, 
    -2.24435873672569, -2.24435873672569, -2.24435873672569, 
    -2.24435873672569), inflation_mean = c(2.36193292302435, 
    2.36193292302435, 2.36193292302435, 2.36193292302435, 2.36193292302435,   2.36193292302435), inflation_diff = structure(c(-0.551575045383031, 
    -0.551575045383031, -0.551575045383031, -0.551575045383031, 
    -0.551575045383031, -0.551575045383031), label = "Inflation, consumer prices (annual %)"), 
    growth_mean = c(2.11454728111128, 2.11454728111128, 2.11454728111128, 
    2.11454728111128, 2.11454728111128, 2.11454728111128), growth_diff = structure(c(-0.462993359244594, 
    -0.462993359244594, -0.462993359244594, -0.462993359244594, 
    -0.462993359244594, -0.462993359244594), label = "GDP growth (annual %)"), 
    corruption_mean = c(1.26648259354364, 1.26648259354364, 1.26648259354364, 
    1.26648259354364, 1.26648259354364, 1.26648259354364), corruption_diff = c(0.699951406456357, 
    0.699951406456357, 0.699951406456357, 0.699951406456357, 
    0.699951406456357, 0.699951406456357), `fdata1$cntry` = structure(c("AT", 
    "AT", "AT", "AT", "AT", "AT"), format.stata = "%2s"), country = structure(c("AT", 
    "AT", "AT", "AT", "AT", "AT"), format.stata = "%2s")), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(
    `fdata1$cntry` = structure("AT", format.stata = "%2s"), .rows = structure(list(
        1:6), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -1L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: In your example, it looks like each country-year appears twice, with two different values of trust?

Comment: Code seems fine. I get expected results running `gapminder::gapminder %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate(lifeExp_mean = mean(lifeExp),
         lifeExp_diff = lifeExp - lifeExp_mean)`.  It will be easier to help if you can share an excerpt of data which demonstrates your problem. Often easiest to use the code `dput(head(data))` to create a code recipe that generates an exact copy of a subset of your data.

Comment: It is survey data, so there are trust score of individual respondents in each country-year, and how do I use the dput function so you can see my data?

Comment: If your data is in an object called `data`, run `dput(data)` or if that's unnecessarily long `dput(head(data))` and then paste the output (which will presumably start with `structure(list(...` into the body of your question above.

Comment: If you run `mean` on a subset of individual observations, it will be weighted by the number of observations each year, which might or might not be what you want, just something to be aware of. So if you have 20 Austrians in 2002 but only one Austrian in 2005, the mean inflation will be much closer to the 2002 value. If that's not what you want, you might want to use `distinct(country, year)` to separately determine an unweighted average and then join that to your original data.

Comment: Okay I have pasted it above, but I think it will only show the observations of one country-wave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require(tidyverse)

data <- mydatacomp %>%  
  merge(.,  countrycode::codelist %>%
          janitor::clean_names() %>%
          select(
            country_name = country_name_en,
            appr = iso2c,
            cont = continent
          ), 
        by.x = "cntry", 
        by.y = "appr") %>%  
  tibble() %>%  
  mutate(cntry = country_name) 


data %>%  
  mutate(unemployment = unemployment %>% as.numeric()) %>%  
  select(cntry, year, wb_inflation, wb_growth, unemployment) %>%  
  group_by(cntry) %>%  
  
  mutate(inflation_mean = mean(wb_inflation, na.rm = TRUE), 
         inflation_diff = wb_inflation - inflation_mean, 
         growth_mean = mean(wb_growth, na.rm = TRUE), 
         growth_diff = wb_growth - growth_mean, 
         unemploy_mean = mean(unemployment, na.rm = TRUE), 
         unemploy_diff = unemployment - unemploy_mean) %>% 
  
  distinct_all() %>%  
  filter(!is.na(year)) %>%  
  arrange(cntry, -year)
```